# Java script array sorting proplem in html and it displays the last element first

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, sorting, clone

when i try to display idArray elements using for loop it started with the last element then start displaying ascending

i tried to display it in console and it display ascending as i want

```js
// magic.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let token = 'AuZQZLEZRmSW3CfnJPXL';
  //var id = 308;

  var row = document.getElementById('row');
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  var title = document.getElementById('outputtitle');
  var id = document.getElementById('outputid');
  var show = document.getElementById('show');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://successsroadv2.herokuapp.com/api/v1/Jobhome',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "Authorization": token
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var myText = '';
      const idArray = data.map(user => user.id);
      const titleArray = data.map(user => user.title);
      //console.log(idArray);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var myText = idArray[i];
        var myText2 = titleArray[i];
        var clone = row.cloneNode(true); //repeat html div
        container.appendChild(clone); //row repeated
        title.innerHTML = myText; //display in title div
        id.innerHTML = myText; //display in id div
        show.innerHTML = myText2; //display in show div
        console.log(myText);
      }

      //const titleArray = data.map(user => user.title);
      //console.log(titleArray);
      /*for (var i = 0; i <data.length; i++) {
          //console.log(data.title);
          myText = data[i].id;
          console.log(myText);
      }
      document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = myText;*/
      //console.log('succ'+data.title);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(`Error ${error}`);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#outputid {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: large;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: black;
}

#outputtitle {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: large;
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
}

#show {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: large;
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
}

#container {
  background-color: darkslategray;
  padding: 60px;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

#row {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Get Try!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- load bootstrap via CDN -->

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- load jquery via CDN -->
  <script src="./js/script1.js"></script>
  <!-- load our javascript file -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="row" id="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4" id="outputtitle"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" id="outputid"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" id="show"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

when i display data in HTML using for loop it starts with the last element and left one div empty and start from the beginning sort ascending i want to display ascending from the first of code
and if displayed the array in console there is no proplem

Comment: First, you need to avoid to use "id" attribute more 1 time. The ID is uniq. You can't duplicate it. Try with class or change your id like "output_1" "output_2" ...

Comment: Id is a json array

Comment: @MoatasemB.Hussien They're talking about duplicating the `id` attribute of HTML elements, not the `id` variable. When you clone a node, the clone gets the same ID as the original.

Comment: All the lines that assign to `innerHTML` are updating the original DIV in the HTML, not part of the clone.

Comment: I tried that but the code still showing the last element first then sort ascending

Comment: And each line that assign to innnerHTML for diff div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML to use classes rather than IDs for the DIVs. Then you can find the nested elements in the cloned DIV, and assign to their HTML.

```js
// magic.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let token = 'AuZQZLEZRmSW3CfnJPXL';
  //var id = 308;

  var row = $('.row');
  var container = $('#container');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://successsroadv2.herokuapp.com/api/v1/Jobhome',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "Authorization": token
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var myText = '';
      const idArray = data.map(user => user.id);
      const titleArray = data.map(user => user.title);
      //console.log(idArray);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var myText = idArray[i];
        var myText2 = titleArray[i];
        var clone = row.clone(true);
        clone.find(".outputtitle").html(myText);
        clone.find(".outputid").html(myText);
        clone.find(".show").html(myText2);
        console.log(myText);
        container.append(clone);
      }
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(`Error ${error}`);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.outputid {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: large;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: black;
}

.outputtitle {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: large;
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
}

.show {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: large;
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
}

#container {
  background-color: darkslategray;
  padding: 60px;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.row {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Get Try!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- load bootstrap via CDN -->

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- load jquery via CDN -->
  <script src="./js/script1.js"></script>
  <!-- load our javascript file -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 outputtitle"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 outputid"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 show"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```